# selecting and purging binary logs through Shell script

Tags: shell-script, shell, mysql

[image]

let suppose this is the master binary log and i want to purge the binary logs upto "mysqld-bin.000002" to free some space in disk.
I want to do this with shell scipt.

Answer (score 0):

If you aren't using binlog processing (replication), then you can remove these permanently.

Remove all /etc/mysql/my.cnf (or equivalent for your Distro) config statements related to bin logging. For example, for recent Distros using MariaDB, this will look similar to...

First, stop MariaDB/MySQL...

```
service mysql stop
```

Then remove /etc/mysql/my.cnf stanzas...

```
log_bin                 = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin
log_bin_index           = /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin.index
```

Then remove old binlog files...

```
rm -fv /var/log/mysql/mariadb-bin*
```

Then restart MariaDB/MySQL...

```
service mysql start
```

Be sure you make these changes with MariaDB/MySQL stopped, or you may end up with lost data.

Comment: through shell script

Answer (score 0):

To *purge* **manually** with **[PURGE BINARY LOGS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/purge-binary-logs.html)** statement:

```
PURGE MASTER LOGS TO 'mysqld-bin.000002';
```

**----------**

To expire binary log files **automatically** after a given number of days - set **[expire_logs_days](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_expire_logs_days)** system variable.
Add the crucial setting into server-specific `my.cnf` file. On Unix-like systems it's usually located at `/etc/my.cnf` or `/etc/mysql/my.cnf`.

Open the file, find `[mysqld]` section and add the setting specifying the needed number of days:

```
[mysqld]
...
expire_logs_days=10
```

After the change is made reload *MySql* service with:

```
/etc/init.d/mysql reload
```

Comment: through shell script

Comment: @RishabhBahukhandi, why reinventing a wheel?

Comment: i want to automated the process so that binary logs will automatically deleted from server

Comment: @RishabhBahukhandi, do you want to remove binary logs automatically after they expire the given number of days?

Comment: yes. i want to delete it automaticaly after they expire the given number

Comment: @RishabhBahukhandi, see my update